# Convert array to a sorted one using only two operations

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I found this question on an online forum: Really interested on how it can be solved:

Given an array A of positive integers. Convert it to a sorted array with minimum cost. The only valid operation are:
1) Decrement with cost = 1
2) Delete an element completely from the array with cost = value of element

This is an interview question asked for a tech company

Comment: And to be clear: you don't have to end with all of the integers you started with?

Comment: yes, we do not need to end with the integers we started with

Comment: i'm curious about a real world application of this operation... can't think of any that make sense to me (obscure optimization algorithms ?)... I mean, we're losing data here !

Comment: @alex - Yes, we're losing data, but perhaps it isn't really data that we're working with. Suppose it is valve settings, and the valves are such that opening them carries a high cost. I haven't thought it through all the way to a plausible scenario, but I think I can get pretty close with that approach.

Comment: @JeffreyLWhitledge i see. valves example makes sense. interesting.

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad I'm assuming the interviewer wanted a fast solution, right? Not just any solution? Because coming up with at least one solution is straightforward.

Comment: @Patrick87: yes, he wanted a fast solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NOTE** : The original answer has been replaced with one in which I have a lot more confidence (and I can explain it, too). Both answers produced the same results on my set of test cases.

You can solve this problem using a dynamic programming approach. The key observation is that it never makes sense to decrement a number to a value not found in the original array. (Informal proof: suppose that you decremented a number `O1` to a value `X` that is not in the original sequence in order to avoid removing a number `O2 > X` from the result sequence. Then you can decrement `O1` to `O2` instead, and reduce the cost by `O2-X`).

Now the solution becomes easy to understand: it is a DP in two dimensions. If we sort the elements of the distinct elements of the original sequence `d` into a sorted array `s`, the length of `d` becomes the first dimension of the DP; the length of `s` becomes the second dimension.

We declare `dp[d.Length,s.Length]`. **The value of `dp[i,j]` is the cost of solving subproblem `d[0 to i]` while keeping the last element of the solution under `s[j]`. Note: this cost includes the cost of eliminating `d[i]` if it is less than `s[j]`.**

The first row `dp[0,j]` is computed as the cost of trimming `d[0]` to `s[j]`, or zero if `d[0] < s[j]`. The value of `dp[i,j]` next row is calculated as the minimum of `dp[i-1, 0 to j] + trim`, where `trim` is the cost of trimming `d[i]` to `s[j]`, or `d[i]` if it needs to be eliminated because `s[j]` is bigger than `d[i]`.

The answer is calculated as the minimum of the last row `dp[d.Length-1, 0 to s.Length]`.

Here is an implementation in C#:

```
static int Cost(int[] d) {
    var s = d.Distinct().OrderBy(v => v).ToArray();
    var dp = new int[d.Length,s.Length];
    for (var j = 0 ; j != s.Length ; j++) {
        dp[0, j] = Math.Max(d[0] - s[j], 0);
    }
    for (var i = 1; i != d.Length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0 ; j != s.Length ; j++) {
            dp[i, j] = int.MaxValue;
            var trim = d[i] - s[j];
            if (trim < 0) {
                trim = d[i];
            }
            dp[i, j] = int.MaxValue;
            for (var k = j ; k >= 0 ; k--) {
                dp[i, j] = Math.Min(dp[i, j], dp[i - 1, k] + trim);
            }
        }
    }
    var best = int.MaxValue;
    for (var j = 0 ; j != s.Length ; j++) {
        best = Math.Min(best, dp[d.Length - 1, j]);
    }
    return best;
}
```

This direct implementation has space complexity of `O(N^2)`. You can reduce it to `O(N)` by observing that only two last rows are used at the same time.

Comment: @dasblinkedlight: can you suggest the DP formulation, as in how can it expressed in terms of the subproblem

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad I added code that implements the DP approach. I added comments to explain what's going on

Comment: I still don't understand the intuition here.  Can you write out, in plain English, what the DP recurrence is and why it's correct?

Comment: @templatetypedef I just replaced the answer with something I can actually explain, and wrote an explanation of what it does. This solution is vastly different from the previous one, and I hope that it is much easier to understand. Both solutions produced the same answers on my test cases, though I would have hard time explaining why the prior one worked.

Comment: +1, but you didn't write how to actually transform the array. While it is obvious for space complexity of `O(N^2)`, your proposal to reduce it to `O(N)` makes this task difficult, may be impossible.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev I think you are right, obtaining a min cost solution (as opposed to simply calculating the min cost) would remain `O(N^2)` space, because we need to trace the path of minimum cost back to the initial element of the sequence.

Comment: can you explain "while keeping the last element of the solution under s[j]"

Comment: @Peter There exist multiple partial solutions to the problem, some of them are sub-optimal. The solution with the cost at `dp[i][j]` considers only the first `i` elements, and additionally does not allow any elements to be greater than `s[j]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that "sorted" means smallest values at the start of the array, given the nature of the allowed operations.

The performance boundary between the two operations occurs when the cost of removing an out of sequence element is equal to the cost of either decrementing all greater-valued elements up to and including the offender, or removing all lesser-valued elements after the offender. You choose between decrementing preceding elements or removing later elements based on why the offending element is out of sequence. If it's less than the previous element, consider decrementing the earlier elements; if it's greater than the next element, consider removing later elements.

Some examples:

```
10 1 2 3 4 5
```

Decrement 10 to 1, cost 9.

```
1 2 3 4 10 4
```

Remove 4, cost 4.

```
1 2 3 4 10 5
```

Remove 5 or decrement 10 to 5, cost 5.

```
5 6 7 8 1 10
```

Remove 1, cost 1.

```
5 6 7 8 6 10
```

Decrement 7 and 8 to 6, cost 3.

```
2 1 1 4 2 4 4 3
```

Decrement the first 1, the first 4 by two, and the other two fours once each, cost 5.

The simplest implementation to find the solutions relies on having set knowledge, so it's very inefficient. Thankfully, the question doesn't care about that. The idea is to walk the array, and make the decision whether to remove or decrement to fix the set when an out of sequence element is encountered. A much more efficient implementation of this would be to use running totals (as opposed to calculate methods) and walk the array twice, forwards and backwards. I've written a mock up of the simpler version, as I think it's easier to read.

Pseudocode, returns total cost:

```
if array.Length < 2 : return 0; // no sorting necessary

resultArray = array.Copy();
int cost = 0;

for i = 0 to array.Length - 1 :

if i > 0 and array[i-1] > array[i] :

if CostToDecrementPreviousItems(i, array[i]) > array[i]) :
resultArray[i] = -1;
cost += array[i];
else :
cost += DecrementItemsThroughIndexGreaterThanValue(resultArray, i, array[i]);
end if

else if i < array.Length - 1 and array[i+1] < array[i] :

if CostToRemoveLaterItems(i, array[i]) > array[i] :
resultArray[i] = -1;
cost += array[i];
else :
cost += RemoveItemsAfterIndexGreaterThanValue(resultArray, i, array[i]);
end if

end if
end for

RemoveNegativeElements(resultArray);
array = resultArray;

return cost;
```

Hopefully the undefined method calls are self explanatory.

Comment: You can convert the `2 1 1 4 2 4 4 3` to `1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3` at the cost of five.

Answer (score 0):

1. Construct decision graph, add start vertex to it. Each vertex contains "trim level", i.e. the value to which should be decremented all array values to the left of current node. Start vertex's "trim level" is infinity. Each edge of the graph has a value, corresponding to the cost of decision.
2. For each array element, starting from the rightmost, do steps 3 .. 5.
3. For each leaf vertex, do steps 4 .. 5.
4. Create up to 2 outgoing edges, (1) with the cost of deleting the array element and (2) with the cost of trimming all elements to the left (exactly, the cost of decreasing "trim level").
5. Connect these edges to newly created vertexes, one vertex for each array element and each "trim level".
6. Find shortest path from start vertex to one of the vertexes, corresponding to leftmost array element. Length of this path equals to the cost of the solution.
7. Decrement and delete array elements according to the decision graph.

This algorithm may be treated as an optimization of brute-force approach. For brute-force search, starting from rightmost array element, construct binary decision tree. Each vertex has 2 outgoing edges, one for "delete" decision, other "trim" decision. Decision cost is associated with each edge. "Trim level" is associated with each vertex. Optimal solution is determined by shortest path in this tree.

Remove every path, that is obviously non-optimal. For example, if the largest element is the last in the array, "trim" decision has cost zero, and "delete" decision is non-optimal. Delete path, starting from this "delete" decision. After this optimization, decision tree is more sparse: some vertexes have 2 outgoing edges, some - only one.

On each depth level, decision tree may have several vertexes with the same "trim level". Subtrees, starting from these vertexes, are identical to each other. That's a good reason to join all these vertexes to one vertex. This transforms tree into graph having at most n<sup>2</sup>/2 vertexes.

**Complexity**

Simplest implementation of this algorithm is O(n<sup>3</sup>), because for each of the O(n<sup>2</sup>) vertexes it computes trimming cost iteratively, in O(n) time.

Repeated trimming cost calculations are not necessary if there is enough memory to store all partial trimming cost results. This may require O(n<sup>2</sup>) or even O(n) space.

With such optimization, this algorithm is O(n<sup>2</sup>). Due to simple structure of the graph, shortest path search has O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity, not O(n<sup>2</sup> * log(n)).

**C++11 implementation (both space and time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>)):**

```
//g++ -std=c++0x
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef unsigned val_t;
typedef unsigned long long acc_t; // to avoid overflows
typedef unsigned ind_t;
typedef std::vector<val_t> arr_t;

struct Node
{
  acc_t trimCost;
  acc_t cost;
  ind_t link;
  bool used;

  Node()
  : trimCost(0)
  , used(false)
  {}
};

class Matrix
{
  std::vector<Node> m;
  ind_t columns;

  public:
  Matrix(ind_t rows, ind_t cols)
  : m(rows * cols)
  , columns(cols)
  {}

  Node& operator () (ind_t row, ind_t column)
  {
    return m[columns * row + column];
  }
};

void fillTrimCosts(const arr_t& array, const arr_t& levels, Matrix& matrix)
{
  for (ind_t row = 0; row != array.size(); ++row)
  {
    for (ind_t column = 0; column != levels.size(); ++column)
    {
      Node& node = matrix(row + 1, column);
      node.trimCost = matrix(row, column).trimCost;

      if (array[row] > levels[column])
      {
        node.trimCost += array[row] - levels[column];
      }
    }
  }
}

void updateNode(Node& node, acc_t cost, ind_t column)
{
  if (!node.used || node.cost > cost)
  {
    node.cost = cost;
    node.link = column;
  }
}

acc_t transform(arr_t& array)
{
  const ind_t size = array.size();

  // Sorted array of trim levels
  arr_t levels = array;
  std::sort(levels.begin(), levels.end());
  levels.erase(
    std::unique(levels.begin(), levels.end()),
    levels.end());

  // Initialize matrix
  Matrix matrix(size + 1, levels.size());
  fillTrimCosts(array, levels, matrix);
  Node& startNode = matrix(size, levels.size() - 1);
  startNode.used = true;
  startNode.cost = 0;

  // For each array element, starting from the last one
  for (ind_t row = size; row != 0; --row)
  {
    // Determine trim level for this array element
    auto iter = std::lower_bound(levels.begin(), levels.end(), array[row - 1]);
    const ind_t newLevel = iter - levels.begin();

    // For each trim level
    for (ind_t column = 0; column != levels.size(); ++column)
    {
      const Node& node = matrix(row, column);
      if (!node.used)
        continue;

      // Determine cost of trimming to current array element's level
      const acc_t oldCost = node.trimCost;
      const acc_t newCost = matrix(row, newLevel).trimCost;
      const acc_t trimCost = (newCost > oldCost)? newCost - oldCost: 0;

      // Nodes for "trim" and "delete" decisions
      Node& trimNode = matrix(row - 1, newLevel);
      Node& nextNode = matrix(row - 1, column);

      if (trimCost)
      {
        // Decision needed, update both nodes
        updateNode(trimNode, trimCost + node.cost, column);
        updateNode(nextNode, array[row - 1] + node.cost, column);
        trimNode.used = true;
      }
      else
      {
        // No decision needed, pass current state to the next row's node
        updateNode(nextNode, node.cost, column);
      }

      nextNode.used = true;
    }
  }

  // Find optimal cost and starting trim level for it
  acc_t bestCost = size * levels.size();
  ind_t bestLevel = levels.size();
  for (ind_t column = 0; column != levels.size(); ++column)
  {
    const Node& node = matrix(0, column);
    if (node.used && node.cost < bestCost)
    {
      bestCost = node.cost;
      bestLevel = column;
    }
  }

  // Trace the path of minimum cost
  for (ind_t row = 0; row != size; ++row)
  {
    const Node& node = matrix(row, bestLevel);
    const ind_t next = node.link;

    if (next == bestLevel && node.cost != matrix(row + 1, next).cost)
    {
      array[row] = 0;
    }
    else if (array[row] > levels[bestLevel])
    {
      array[row] = levels[bestLevel];
    }

    bestLevel = next;
  }

  return bestCost;
}

void printArray(const arr_t& array)
{
  for (val_t val: array)
    if (val)
      std::cout << val << ' ';
    else
      std::cout << "* ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  arr_t array({9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1});
  printArray(array);

  acc_t cost = transform(array);
  printArray(array);
  std::cout << "Cost=" << cost << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this or give an example?  I'm not sure I see why or how this works.

Comment: @templatetypedef, it's not easy to give convincing example for n^2 space algorithm. I added some explanations. If any part of this is not clear enough, please let me know.